# Discord.js use Attachment from other Message to update Image in Embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am generating a Picture from a Canvas (it's in `imageBuffer`), and making a MessageAttachment from it:

```
const attachment = new MessageAttachment(imageBuffer, "bufferedImg.png");
```

I then create an embed object like this, which includes the image as a file attachment:

```
const messageObj = {
  embed: {
    title: "The Image",
    files: [
        attachment
    ],
    image: {
        url: 'attachment://bufferedImg.png'
    }
  }
}
```

The first time I send this object to the text-channel ( `this.channel.send(messageObj).then(msg => this.displayMessage = msg`), it works like it should. It posts the embed with the picture in it.
But when I generate a new picture / attachment, recreate the embed object, and then edit the Embed to use that new attachment ( `this.displayMessage.edit(messageObj)`), it doesn't work.

The picture doesn't update.

I also tried giving it a random name, to make sure it's not just using the old cached image - That simply disconnected the old picture from the embed - But the new picture didn't appear.

On another Stackoverflow post, someone said the Discord API just **doesn't allow you to update the attachments of a Message**. But someone also said, you **can change the image url**.

So, my idea was, to **send a new Message with the new picture as an attachment**. And then in the old message, **change the url of the image to the attachment of the new message**.
For example I post a new message containing bufferedImg2.png as an attachment, and in the old message, where the link points to `attachment://bufferedImg.png`, i just change it to use `newMessage:attachment://bufferedImg2.png`.

The question is:
**How can I make the url point to an attachment of another message?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I edit an image inside an embed discord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63050380/how-do-i-edit-an-image-inside-an-embed-discord)

Comment: @Ant No it doesn't. That is the post I was referring to with "On another Stackoverflow post, someone said the Discord API just doesn't allow you to update the attachments of a Message. But someone also said, you can change the image url."

Comment: From what I have read from the DiscordJS you can change the url of an image but not of an uploaded image, for example if you send the link to a gif, you can change that link and it should change the preview.

Comment: I would recommend trying out `npm i discordjs/discord.js` that installs the in-dev version wich can do all of the new things, but will most likely break some old code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve this using the latest discordjs (13.0.1) (Typescript):

**1. Create & Send the first message which you want to update.**

```
let embed = new MessageEmbed().setImage(INSERT_YOUR_FIRST_URL)
const displayMessage = await channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
```

**2. Send the second message & Get the URL.** you can send it to a different channel or server if you want to keep the channel clean

```
const msg = await channel.send({ files: [attachment] })
const url = msg.attachments.first()?.url ?? '';
```

**3. Edit your first message.**

```
embed = new MessageEmbed().setImage(url)
displayMessage.edit({ embeds: [embed] })
```

Comment: Oh wow, I thought my idea was ridiculous and impossible, but this actually works. This is exactly what i wanted. Thank you so much!

Comment: I thought the same as there are a lot of changes in the syntax between discordjs versions which makes most guides and tutorials deprecated. You are welcome and good luck :).